# data connection and wifi at same time

Tags: android, network-programming

i want to turn on data connection and wi-fi at same time. how can i do that? Thanks in advance :)

like this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.opbyte.superdownload&hl=en

I tried to go through Android WiFi tether source code (http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/) to understand its working. i want to use both interfaces to be able to download a file. is it possible at all ?